# Unable to save rendered image

Tags: image

[image: unable to save image, please help]

I use Ubuntu Trusty Thar, Blender v2.69.
I'm unable to save rendered image; the only save dialog I get is the one to save as a Blender file.
I watched the tuts, I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and get *Save as blender file* option and was unable to change.

Tried <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and get the same panel with no option to save other than as a Blender file

Comment: Image is saved with F3 button, without any additional buttons (Fn won't be recognized as image saving). Shift+Ctrl+S will open dialog for saving file as a new one as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Although <kbd>F3</kbd> didn't work I found the *Image* menu entry located in the bottom left corner shown on screenshot.

[image]